# mysql actualizar una tabla con una vista que usa la misma tabla

Tags: mysql

He creado una vista de una tabla que calcula una columna con valores de varias tablas.

Ahora me gustaría que esa columna se reflejara en la tabla original sin embargo  me da error al hacerlo

uso esta consulta:

```
UPDATE listado_armario l
SET competencia = 
(SELECT competencia FROM 
listado_armarios_view WHERE l.id = id)
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

```
 SQL Error [1443] [HY000]: The definition of table 'listado_armarios_view' prevents operation UPDATE on table 'l'.
```

listado_armarios_view usa GROUP BY y COUNT aparte de unas cuantas formulas

La columna competencia se calcula con datos de la propia tabla y datos de otras tres tablas

Quizás en lugar de crear una vista debiera hacer otro tipo de proceso?

Comment: Ese error suele ocurrir porque la vista hace uso de la tabla `listado_armario` que es la misma que quieres actualizar. De todos modos, salvo contadas excepciones, hay que evitar el uso de vistas. Es mejor que hagas tus operaciones implicando directamente cada tabla que sea necesaria en la consulta.

Comment: Si todos modos quieres usar la vista, puedes intentarlo con un `JOIN`, algo así más o menos: **`UPDATE listado_armario l
       JOIN listado_armarios_view lv
       ON lv.id = l.id
SET    l.competencia = lv.competencia;`**

Comment: He usado una vista porque no sé otro modo de hacer el calculo, acepto alternativas

Comment: ¿Probaste con el `JOIN`? Si quieres hacerlo sin la vista, puedes incorporar la consulta que haces en ella en ese código, en la parte del `JOIN`. OJO: haz una copia de seguridad de tu tabla antes de realizar cualquier cambio.

Comment: @A.Cedano por qué no hay que usar vistas? O te refieres en particular a los updates?

Comment: @ffflabs durante mucho tiempo se ha considerado que las vistas tienen un impacto negativo en el rendimiento, por ejemplo, en `MySQL` una vista actúa como una tabla virtual. Cuando uno empieza con SQL tiene la tentación de usarlas al creer que simplifican las cosas o al creer que va más rápido una consulta corta que hecha mano de varias vistas que una consulta escandalosamente larga que no usa ninguna vista. Pues jamás una consulta basada en vistas irá más rápido. Eso no quiere decir que no sean útiles, para casos en los que no quieres mostrar toda la tabla a ciertos usuarios por ejemplo...

Comment: ...debido a cuestiones de seguridad. Para más detalles puedes consultar [aquí](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16376) y también [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483604/5587982).

Comment: Te entiendo @A.Cedano y respeto mucho tu opinión desde que empecé aquí hace un par de años. Es que yo tengo bastante experiencia en MySQL, también tiendo a evitar las vistas porque imponen rigideces (exportar un dump en AWS es un parto) pero en otros casos encapsulan lógica que sería complejo meter en el código. En la actualidad, aunque tengo dos certificaciones en MySQL, me voy a ojos cerrados con PostgreSQL (vistas materializadas y constructos WITH) y mirando atrás digo: me certifiqué en una BBDD que quiere hacer todo pero está atrofiada en mucho. Gracias por la grata discusión!

Comment: @A.Cedano a lo mejor serviría usar una tabla temporal... depende de la cantidad de datos puede ser un desperdicio... pero son el mejor sucedáneo al constructo WITH